# reactjs web app with (local database) like sqllite with

Tags: reactjs, sqlite

I am a web developer using react .. and I want to connect my application with local database like sqlite.
The scenario is the website is using API which I developed but I want the application to create a local database in the client device in order to insert data on it and then in other time I will upload this inserted data (on local database) to the server >>>

The question is can I do this:

1. is there any local database can i create it in the client device?
2. or can i create file and us it so store data and then use this data again?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ???